# Why doesn't ORDER BY 'id' 'desc' return a syntax error?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I was testing some apparently wrong code and was quite sure it should return a syntax error. But it didn't. The following query works without errors (albeit doesn't sort the table either, *which at least meets my expectations*):

```
SELECT * FROM dummy ORDER BY 'id' 'desc';
```

Interestingly, that

```
SELECT * FROM dummy ORDER BY id 'desc';
```

*does* produce a syntax error.

How does MySQL interpret two strings after `ORDER BY`? What does it take these strings for?  Here is the [MCVE](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/82647cf0f24434ea04a6f72ad61d1565/)

Comment: `does produce a syntax error` ... what is the syntax error?

Comment: It should be shown on the MCVE. The quite expected `You have an error in your SQL syntax near ''desc''` one

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat ("For quoted strings, concatenation can be performed by placing the strings next to each other") - study.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM dummy ORDER BY 'id' 'desc';
```

evaluates to

```
SELECT * FROM dummy ORDER BY 'iddesc';
```

I.e. ORDER BY a (constant) string literal - which doesn't affect the ORDER BY at all.

**Note:** This is ANSI/ISO SQL standard, a character literal can be built up by several parts, without having explicit concatenation. (Almost correct, a new-line is required as separator.)

Comment: Interesting! But how and why Mysql concatenates two strings here?

Comment: @YourCommonSense - MySQL has an unfortunate history of trying to implement effectively  "Do What I Mean" . Whilst most database systems will generate syntax errors if you've entered something questionable, MySQL will often prefer to run *something*, *anything*, that gives you a result set.

Comment: This is ANSI/ISO SQL standard, a character literal can be built up by several parts, without having explicit concatenation.